# Android Onboarding but only one item can be seen in adapter

Tags: android, android-studio

```
private void setupOnbaordingItems()
    {
        List<OnboardingItem> onboardingItems=new ArrayList<>();

        OnboardingItem itemsPayOnline=new OnboardingItem();
        itemsPayOnline.setTitle("Pay Your Bill Online");
        itemsPayOnline.setDescription("Electric bill payment is a feature of online , mobile and telephone and banking ");
        itemsPayOnline.setImage(R.drawable.pay_online);

        OnboardingItem itemsOnTheWay=new OnboardingItem();
        itemsPayOnline.setTitle("Your Food Is On The Way");
        itemsPayOnline.setDescription("Our delievery rider is on the way to deliver your order ");
        itemsPayOnline.setImage(R.drawable.on_thw_way);

        OnboardingItem itemEatTogather=new OnboardingItem();
        itemsPayOnline.setTitle("Eat Togather");
        itemsPayOnline.setDescription("Enjoy your meal and have a great day,Dont forgot oto rate us ");
        itemsPayOnline.setImage(R.drawable.eat_togather);

        onboardingItems.add(itemsPayOnline);
        onboardingItems.add(itemsOnTheWay);
        onboardingItems.add(itemEatTogather);

        onboardingAdapter=new OnboardingAdapter(onboardingItems);
    }
```

- Adapter shows only one item where i want to add 3 onboard stories to
  adapter

### Help me to solve the issue

**activity_onboarding.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".OnboardingActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonOnboardingAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:cornerRadius="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/onboardingViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutOnboardingIndicators"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonOnboardingAction"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/buttonOnboardingAction"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttonOnboardingAction"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

- The item container for the activity xml file
- I am not able to find the error if anybody can help me find it would
  be great help to me

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageOnboarding"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

---

- I have three onboarding items in my  function where adapter at a
  time shows only one item.

---

Comment: Hey, show the code of Adapter and maybe the layout of item.

Comment: Set root layout height to wrap_content for adapter item

Comment: I have added the layout files too